# Retrospectively translate cucumber.json into modern single page cucumber.html

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumberjs

I have a recent cucumber.json file and I want to generate the HTML rendition off it.

I cannot rerun the scenario, but instead need to translate my historic json file.

I want the same single page, multiple feature, rendition I would get today from the "html" reporter that I get with cuccumber-jvm.

Is there a way for me to retrospectively translate the json to html.

I am hoping there is an existing lib or tool for this.

---

As far as do-it-youself ...

I note that the io.cucumber.core.plugin.HtmlFormatter was designed to be driven of the events created during a cuke execution, and it revolves around "Envelope" objects.

However, the Envelope class doesn't look like the json that's in the cucumber.json so a simple rehydration won't work.

Seems the problem is to convert from cucumber.json to Envelope is there an existing way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not possible. There are other tools that convert the json into a report though.